# T-SQL Find local maxima - sum of maximum of running value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

There is a table that have values of running value that sometimes reset:

```
--------------------------------------
|         Time           |   Value   |
--------------------------------------
|2018-08-11 00:16:00.000 |     4     |
|2018-08-11 00:17:00.000 |     8     |
|2018-08-11 00:18:00.000 |     12    |
|2018-08-11 00:19:00.000 |     16    |
|2018-08-11 00:20:00.000 |     27    |
|2018-08-11 00:21:00.000 |     0     |   -- Doesn't have to be neccessary 0
|2018-08-11 00:22:00.000 |     3     |
|2018-08-11 00:23:00.000 |     5     |
|2018-08-11 00:24:00.000 |     4     |   -- Even going down, not passing the limit value
|2018-08-11 00:25:00.000 |     12    |
|2018-08-11 00:26:00.000 |     18    |
--------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying is to achieve a total SUM of all local Maxima. It is finding the biggest element before reset - simply would be: `27`, `5`, `18`.

**BUT:** There is also special case, where the local maximum should ignore small flaps (because the running value can sometimes be a bit lower). In the example above, it should ignore the value `5`, because the next value is `4` and then it continues to grow. **Actual result would be:** `27`,`18`.

---

**Result:** 27 + 18 = 45

---

**Example SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
  [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Value] [real] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:16:00' AS DATETIME),'4' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:17:00' AS DATETIME),'8' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:18:00' AS DATETIME),'12');
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:19:00' AS DATETIME),'16');
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:20:00' AS DATETIME),'27');
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:21:00' AS DATETIME),'0' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:22:00' AS DATETIME),'3' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:23:00' AS DATETIME),'5' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:24:00' AS DATETIME),'4' );
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:25:00' AS DATETIME),'12');
INSERT INTO Data ([Time], [Value]) VALUES(CAST('2018-08-11 00:26:00' AS DATETIME),'18');
```

---

**Proposed solution/what I've tried:** I thought about trying to find local maximum by `ROW_NUMBER()` over the `Time` column and joining the same table with +1 row number. Then I can compare 2 values and if the gap is too big, I will simply ignore the fact. However, last entry is not selected there. And I'm not too sure about optimization / if the proposed solution is something that will work as intended.

```
WITH TAB0 AS (
    SELECT
        *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time)
    FROM
        Data
)
SELECT
    t1.Time,
    t1.Value as MT1,
    t2.Value as MT2
FROM
    TAB0 t1
    INNER JOIN TAB0 t2 ON t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
        AND (t2.Value + 1) < t1.Value                --put the limit here instead of "+1"
    ORDER BY t1.Time;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local maxima, the logic would be:

```
select sum(value)
from (select d.*,
             lag(value) over (order by time) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (order by time) as next_value
      from d
     ) d
where value > prev_value and value > next_value;
```

Your enhanced conditions seem mostly about setting other limits; this does what you describe:

```
select sum(value)
from (select d.*,
             lag(value) over (order by time) as prev_value,
             lead(value) over (order by time) as next_value,
             lead(value, 2) over (order by time) as next_value2
      from d
     ) d
where value > prev_value and value > next_value and
      value > next_value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the Gordon's answer, he set me on the right path, we need to work with `previous` and `next` values. Which this query does:

```
select d.*,
    lag(value) over (order by time) as prev_value,
    lead(value) over (order by time) as next_value
from data d
```

By comparing previous and next values, we can filter the maximum (and add the limits there):

```
select (value)     -- Gets all the values, if there is " SUM(Value) " - sum of all values will be get
from (select d.*,
         lag(value) over (order by time) as prev_value,
         lead(value) over (order by time) as next_value
  from data d
  ) d
where value > (prev_value +1) and value > (next_value +1);

/*   +1 in the last row sets the limit to 1      */
```

And now we need to handle the limit cases, which can be simply done by setting `NULL` to `0`.

---

**Full query:**

```
select SUM(value)
from (select d.*,
         ISNULL(lag(value) over (order by time), 0) as prev_value,
         ISNULL(lead(value) over (order by time), 0) as next_value
  from data d
) d
where value > (prev_value + 1) and value > (next_value + 1);
```